# How Do I use autofs to map a USB drive by its ID?

Tags: linux, rhel, automounting, external-hdd, autofs

### Goal

- I have a USB drive -- let's say the drive's ID is */dev/disk/by-id/thediskid*
- I would like to mount the drive -- by ID -- to a folder (let's call it /MOUNT_FOLDER)

### Question

- What is the best way to do this using autofs?

### Current Attempt

**/etc/auto.master:**

```
+auto.master
/localam auto.linux
/[another mount]  [auto.othermount] --timeout=5 -- ghost
/MOUNT_FOLDER auto.ext-usb --timeout=5
/ -
```

**/etc/auto.ext-usb:**

```
/MOUNT_FOLDER /dev/disk/by-id/thediskid
```

I know I'm missing something but I can't seem to get a good lead on what the proper syntax is.

New to Linux; appreciate a pass if I'm overlooking something simple. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the only usb-drive you ever want to mount, or do you want to do something more generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constellation /MOUNT_FOLDER is the base directory where subdirectories will be mounted by the indirect mount-map auto.ext-usb.

See `man 5 autofs` for further details.

Example:

```
usbdisk -fstype=vfat,uid=yourworkingusername :/dev/disk/by-id/thediskid
```

If you `cd /MOUNT_FOLDER/usbdisk` your usbdisk will be mounted there (I assume it is vfat formatted).

You can use **/etc/fstab** instead - but then you will to have to mount "by hand".

The entry in /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/thediskid /MOUNT_FOLDER vfat defaults,user,noauto 0 0
```

After that you can mount the USB-Disk as ordinary user with `mount /MOUNT_FOLDER`.

Comment: Nils, not sure I follow you completely, though what you're saying sounds possible. In this case, how would you recommend accomplishing mounting the contents of the USB disk into the /MOUNT_FOLDER location? Also, am I using the wrong tool in autofs (is it recommended that I just use /etc/fstab instead, for example?)

Comment: @goober if you want to use the automounter-mechanism using indirect maps is the "recommended" way. If you really want to use the main directory as mountpoint you can define your entry directly in the direct map auto.master - but changes in auto.master will only be activated by restarting autofs (as opposed to indirect maps). I'll update my answer about /etc/fstab

Comment: I'm not attempting to argue your solution that it's the recommended way. My issue is that I'm getting the syntax wrong. In order to mount a usb drive by id using autofs, could you show me the proper way to configure the files given the information I've provided initially? I understand the concept generally when it's explained but implementing your suggestions seems to be going wrong somewhere.

Comment: @goober I tried this myselv and updated my answer.

Comment: @SeanKilleen The problem with indirect maps is that you will have to use a subdirectory. There are two ways around this: a) use a direct map b) use a soft-link /MOUNT_FOLDER that points to /MOUNT_FOLDER/usbdisk.

Answer (score 4):

1. add to `/etc/auto.master`

   ```
   /var/autofs/removable   /etc/auto.removable     --timeout=2
   ```
2. add to `/etc/auto.removable`

   ```
   theDiskLabel         -fstype=ext4,rw,gid=1000,umask=002       :/dev/disk/by-uuid/thediskid
   ```
3. restart autofs service

   ```
   sudo service autofs restart
   ```
4. Access your directory, thats it!

   ```
   cd /var/autofs/removable/theDiskLabel
   ```